# Signal R notify client

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

i am completely newbie to Signal R Core. I would like to know the best practice how to notify client about event which  has happened in my system. i have a real task which is following

I am subscribed to events call_begin and call_end when my eventHandler handles that events i would like to notify about them clients via signal r. So far i have done this via this code.

```
 private void  CallStartedEventHandler(CallData callData) 
    {
        _callNotifierHub.NotifyAboutCallStartedOrEnded("call_started", callData.CallID);
    }

    private void  CallEndedEventHandler(CallMetadata callMetadata) 
    {
         _callNotifierHub.NotifyAboutCallStartedOrEnded("call_ended", callData.CallID);
    }
```

And this is my hub code

```
 public class CallNotifierHub : Hub, ICallNotifierHub
{
    public async Task NotifyAboutCallStartedOrEnded(string message, long callId)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("NotifyAboutCallEvent", message, callId);
    }
}
```

And i am interested is this ok? Any suggestions?Would this eve n work???

Comment: Does it work? ...

Comment: I could not managed to test it so far i have some issues with the remote server, which will generate that events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to send message/notification to clients from outside a hub, to  achieve it you can use the SignalR `IHubContext`. For more information, you can refer to the following article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-3.1